# Cannot set headers after they are sent : response.redirect() NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need to user diferents `response.redirect()` but I get an error in my console.

**Error code :** `Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

**My code :**

```
    // on vérifie si max par semaine atteint si c'est le cas on supprime la resa
    if (moment(createdItem.date).isSame(new Date(), 'week')) {
      createdItem.destroy().then(function() {
        request.flash('danger', 'Total de réservation maximum par semaine atteint');
        response.redirect('/user/__show');
      });
    }

    // dans le cas d'un abonnement trouvé on touche pas aux cartes
    if (findedRpaUserServiceSub) {
      request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
      response.redirect('/user/__show');
    }

    // si on trouve une carte mais sans abonnement
    if (findedRpaUserServiceCard) {
      if ((findedRpaUserServiceCard.remaining_services - 1) === 0) {
        findedRpaUserServiceCard.destroy().then(function() {
          request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
          response.redirect('/user/__show');
        });
      } else {
        findedRpaUserServiceCard.update({
          remaining_services: findedRpaUserServiceCard.remaining_services - 1
        }).then(function() {
          request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
          response.redirect('/user/__show');
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting the user multiple times. These if are not exclusives. You should, at minima, use `else if` statement

```
// on vérifie si max par semaine atteint si c'est le cas on supprime la resa
    if (moment(createdItem.date).isSame(new Date(), 'week')) {
      createdItem.destroy().then(function() {
        request.flash('danger', 'Total de réservation maximum par semaine atteint');
        response.redirect('/user/__show');
      });
    }

    // dans le cas d'un abonnement trouvé on touche pas aux cartes
    else if (findedRpaUserServiceSub) {
      request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
      response.redirect('/user/__show');
    }

    // si on trouve une carte mais sans abonnement
    else if (findedRpaUserServiceCard) {
      if ((findedRpaUserServiceCard.remaining_services - 1) === 0) {
        findedRpaUserServiceCard.destroy().then(function() {
          request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
          response.redirect('/user/__show');
        });
      } else {
        findedRpaUserServiceCard.update({
          remaining_services: findedRpaUserServiceCard.remaining_services - 1
        }).then(function() {
          request.flash('success', 'Réservation ajoutée');
          response.redirect('/user/__show');
        });
      }
    }
    else {
     // something else
    }
```

You can also add a `return` inside each if to stop further processing or use `next()` if you are using expressjs to go to the next middleware.